# Code using jQuery in Chrome content script fails to work

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that injects content into the tumblr 'new posts' page, which has an element with id tag_editor. But I can't get at it using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#tag_editor"));
});
```

just gives me [object Object], which I assume means that it failed to find an element. If I use document.getElementById instead of $, it works. I have jQuery.js in my manifest.json, so it's not that jQuery isn't loading. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

object Object means its returning a jQuery object. You cant alert an object. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( $("#tag_editor") );
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#tag_editor").html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery function, `$()`, returns an object; hence your `alert` message. If you want the underlying DOM object, say:

```
alert($("#tag_editor")[0]);
```

or

```
alert($("#tag_editor").get(0));
```

Comment: That would explain it! Thanks!